# How to solve this on spoj?

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve [this spoj problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ONEZERO/).

Problem Statement : Certain positive integers have their decimal representation consisting only of ones and zeros, and having at least one digit one, e.g. 101. If a positive integer does not have such a property, one can try to multiply it by some positive integer to find out whether the product has this property.

I am trying BFS approach by starting with 1(Since first number should be one) and each step i am queuing num*10(to append a zero) and num*10+1(to append a one) and checking whether it is divisible by the input number.

I think my approach is right but i could not handle large integers. Already i am using unsigned long long int. I read few SO articles and forums for help but couldn't understand them. What i came to know was there was a way to do this without storing the entire number.

Could some one throw some light on it?

Below is the code I've tried

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<sstream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
unsigned long long int BFS(unsigned long long int s,unsigned long long int k)
{
unsigned long long int x;
    queue<unsigned long long int>q;
    q.push(s);
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        x=q.front();
        q.pop();
        if(x%k==0)
        {
            return x;
        }
       q.push(x*10);
       q.push(x*10+1);
    }
}
int main()
{
unsigned long long int t,n;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n;
        cout<<BFS(1,n)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to find, exactly?  What is the output supposed to be?

Comment: The problem statement is completely unclear, and in your revised statement, the answer is trivially 1 in every case.  So I still have no idea what you are even trying to do.  Can you give a specific test case and solve it?

Comment: I think the problem statement is clear. If a number is not composed of only zeroes and ones(Except the first digit which should be always one) we can multiply with a number to make it fit to this property. And we have to find the value composing of ones and zeroes which is _input-value_ times the _multiplier_ composing of ones and zeroes

Comment: Test cases 1)input: 11011 output :11011 (already satisfies the property)                 2)input : 17 output :11101 (17*a constant value)

Comment: All right.  In the case of 17, what's the one possible final digit of the other factor that makes the last digit of the product come out right?  (Zero cannot be the last digit of the answer, or we could divide by 10.). Given that, what are the two possible values of the second-to-last digit?  Can you generalize this approach?

Comment: From the description of the question, 100 is one of the numbers that "have their decimal representation consisting only of ones and zeros, and having at least one digit one". So if you input 50, you should get 100 as it is an integer multiple of 50. Your algorithm won't output 100 as it tries only 50, 500, 501, etc.

Comment: @SiyuanRen The code works perfectly fine for 50. And if you see the code clearly i am not doing it as you said, that is 50,500,501... but i am doing it 1,10,11... The start value is 1 and not the input number

Comment: OK, I was wrong. Now can you clarify what you mean about "not handling large integers"? Are the integers overflowed in calculation, or does the computation take too long to finish?

Comment: Like most SPOJ problems this is a math problem. You need to produce a *proof*, then (trivially) transform it to code.